# Associate hash value to local var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to associate the values of `"from"` and `"length"` to the `a` and `b` variables present in the each, but all the hash values are stored in `a`. How do I save the values of `"from"` in the `a` and of `"length"` in `b`?

```
array.each_value do |a , b|
end
```

array's puts:

[image: screenshot array]

Comment: Please share what your input data looks like (in your question, not as image), the linked image doesn't explain this well, because it only shows some hashes, but not how they are connected to each other. And tell us exactly what the output should look like.

Comment: array.each do |key, value|
  a = value["from"]
  b = value["length"]
  # Do something with a and b
end

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes the data structure is:

```rb
array = [
  { "from" => 0, "length" => 4 },
  { "from" => 4, "length" => 3 },
  # ...
]
```

Since you tagged the question with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) I'll assume you have access to the Rails helpers. In which case we can use [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck) to extract specific key values.

```rb
array.pluck("from", "length").each do |a, b|
  # ...
end
```

Without the Rails `pluck` helper you can use [`values_at`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/hash#method-i-values_at):

```rb
array.each do |range_hash|
  a, b = range_hash.values_at("from", "length")
  # ...
end
```

Or combine it with [`map`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/enumerable#method-i-map) if you really want to pass them as block arguments. I personally find the former more readable.

```rb
array
  .map { |range_hash| range_hash.values_at("from", "length") }
  .each do |a, b|
    # ...
  end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, if instead there is a string in the "length" of array's puts?  instead of an integer.

Comment: i try with pluck method, but it doesn't work beacuse, just i said, thare was a character as array's lenght. terminal give me "implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Comment: @JACKoJONS It would probably help to get the correct data structure to start with. This answer is based on an assumption. Could you add `p array` (instead of `puts array`) in your code and add the output to the question (as codeblock, not an image)? Is the exception pointing to the code provided in this answer? Or are you using `a` or `b` in a way that raises the exception?

Comment: sorry, this is the complete array's puts : https://ibb.co/DtVF3XZ

Comment: but i dont understand why it gave me this error. I only wrote "array.pluck("from", "lenght").each do |a,b|"

Comment: @JACKoJONS The screenshot provided still shows no reason why `array.pluck("from", "length")` wouldn't work. **Could you please use `p` instead of `puts`?** `puts` hides arrays. I suspect your array might contain nested arrays, for example the structure `[[{ "from" => 0, "length" => 4 }]]` will throw the mentioned exception, because it's trying to access `"from"` and `"two"` on the nested array. Yet it still prints the same as `[{ "from" => 0, "length" => 4 }]` with `puts` (but not with `p`).